# how to use google chart using dynamic data from json

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

iam using mvc, i want to connect my data to google pie chart. so i used json to get list of names and their count using the following code

```
public JsonResult list()
        {
     var result= list.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Select(i => new { word = i.Key, count = i.Count() 
return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Using the google chart API

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "list",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        var data = google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Certificate details',
            is3D: true,
        };    
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

i want to know how to get list of key value pairs of my data into pie chart.
i have googled for long time, everybody is giving code example with php.
Thankyou.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would want to use server-side for this, but I can help you parse the data client-side.  What does `jsonData` contain?

Comment: My Json will return the array like this= [{"word":group1,"count":1},{"word":group2,"count":2},{"word":group3,"count":1},{"word":group4,"count":1}]. how to parse from client side.  Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can parse that data client-side like this:

```
function drawChart () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "list",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            // assumes "word" is a string and "count" is a number
            data.addColumn('string', 'word');
            data.addColumn('number', 'count');

            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([jsonData[i].word, jsonData[i].count]);
            }

            var options = {
                title: 'Certificate details',
                is3D: true
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this code and choose the color of each slice?

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic handler to provide some methods to work with dinamic google charts.

First you `register` the data or part of it. After this, you are able to  `render` when necessary.

Look at: http://github.com/ahlechandre/chart-handler